# When will signers be broadcast on a PoA network?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have sort of working PoA but it seems unpredictable.

> clique.getSigners()
>   ["0x10799bda8ec85f99e50861571ee8884689ebfbb8", "0x16cfa8b0b01e2bbb0ebfdc49a9438a5c1368dcb6", "0x242f75170b0b38917995724bd5aef1aa07d31fff", "0x5ab4bf732559119d73abbb7dfee295746adf1edc", "0x9440c75f6f7c32ee633a206ace282ce9bd58c822", "0x9a3c01f1ab50e16b3ac083c9f6826429fd1f2c75", "0xc7c776a8b564228ecca00c86d1d80b431aa9f4f3", "0xe578e38bca4f0d1bf4e90be7da9a1bd58277c5b7", "0xf39995b718ae7a0075557f9781425b92fd8b28a6"]
>   clique.proposals
>   {
>     0x5ab4bf732559119d73abbb7dfee295746adf1edc: true
>   }

I get the account ending 'edc' as a proposal and also the actual node for it (remote) does not get any voting rights.

Why does the account 0x5ab4bf732559119d73abbb7dfee295746adf1edc appear in the proposal list and also the GetSigners list?